# Using with Firebase / Expo query to Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

So I am trying to keep my code clean and build different files for querying... So I may be taking this harder than it needs to be.

I building a react-native app using Expo CLI.

I have created 3 files, one is my firebase config file,
one is a query file
then the actual file that is using that query.

it looks ok to me... but I get this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating'_firebase.firebase.firestore')
```

Here is my config file

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
  appId: "app-id",
  measurementId: "G-measurement-id"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Then I have a a query file, basically acting as the API layer

```
import { firebase } from "./firebase";

const db = firebase.firestore();

const getListings = () => {
  db.collection("listings").get();
};

export default {
  getListings,
};
```

Then I am trying to view the queried data.

```
import listingApi from "../api/listings";
function ListingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [listings, setListings] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadListings();
  }, []);

  const loadListings = async () => {
    const response = await listingApi.getListings();
    setListings(response.data);
  };
```

This is my first time ever using Firebase or cloud firestore... so im really confused.

Answer (score -2):

The error message is telling you that '_firebase.firebase.firestore' data is returning as undefined, this means the document you requested doesn't exist.

At the officiald documentation of [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/#using-expo-with-firestore), is recommended to put the firebase config information in the same file with your code in order to use firebase, for example:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = { ... }  // apiKey, authDomain, etc. (see above)

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const dbh = firebase.firestore();

dbh.collection("characters").doc("mario").set({
  employment: "plumber",
  outfitColor: "red",
  specialAttack: "fireball"
})
```

Comment: i am using expo, so using the react-native documents wont be helpful. The documents in expo does not really help too much.